# Absolute and absolute relative error (numerical errors)

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-stability

I'd like to understand how absolute and relative errors work in order to write some code.

Suppose, we have `x1*=4.54 x2*=3.00` and `x3*=15.0`, accuracy: 3 digits.
How do we define:
  a. the absolute error of `x1*-x2*+x3*` and
  b. the absolute relative error of `x1*x2*/x3*` 
  c. the accuracy in a and b.

Trying to make sense:
a.
    |e1|<=0.5*10^(-3)

```
|e2|<=0.5*10^(-3)

|e3|<=0.5*10^(-3)
```

or 
    |e1|<=0.5*10^(-2)

```
|e2|<=0.5*10^(-2)

|e3|<=0.5*10^(-1)
```

and then `|e|<=|e1|+|e2|+|e3|=(15+4+3)*0.5*10^(-3)`
b. `|r|<=|r1|+|r2|+|r3|=|e1/x1*|+|e2/x2*|+|e3/x3*|`

Comment: There's an _absolute error_ and a _relative error_. What is an "absolute relative error"? O_O

Comment: what do you mean by the stars at the end of x1, x2 and x3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Of course you can't find the actual error because you don't know the actual values.  Thus you want to *constrain* the error.  First note that we're talking about rounding error (as you've done), thus the maximum that each variable can be off by is 0.5 of its precision, i.e.

|e<sub>1</sub>| <= 0.005

|e<sub>2</sub>| <= 0.005

|e<sub>3</sub>| <= 0.05

For the absolute error of x<sub>1</sub>-x<sub>2</sub>+x<sub>3</sub>, the worst case is that all of the errors add together linearly,  I.e.:

|e<sub>123</sub>| <= 0.005+0.005+0.05 = 0.06.

Because it's **absolute** error, you don't have to rescale by what the actual values of x<sub>1</sub>... are.

For the relative error of (x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>)/x<sub>3</sub>, it's a little more complicated--you have to actually propogate (multiply) out the error.  But, if you assume that the error is much smaller than the value, i.e. |e<sub>1</sub>| << x<sub>1</sub> (which is a good approximation for this case), then you get the equation that you used in 'b':

|r| = |r<sub>123</sub> / (x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>/x<sub>3</sub>) |  ~<  |e<sub>1</sub>/x<sub>1</sub>| + |e<sub>2</sub>/x<sub>2</sub>| + |e<sub>3</sub>/x<sub>3</sub>|

Because this is **relative** error, you *do* have to rescale the errors by the actual values.

So, overall, you just about had it right --- just a little trouble with the `absolute error`.